# Exported scraped .csv file from AWS EC2 to AWS MYSQL database

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-design, amazon-ec2

I have a Python Scraper that I run periodically in my free tier AWS EC2 instance using Cron that outputs a csv file every day containing around 4-5000 rows with 8 columns. I have been ssh-ing into it from my home Ubuntu OS and adding the new data to a SQLite database which I can then use to extract the data I want.

Now I would like to try the free tier AWS MySQL database so I can have the database in the Cloud and pull data from it from my terminal on my home PC. I have searched around and found no direct tutorial on how this could be done. It would be great if anyone that has done this could give me a conceptual idea of the steps I would need to take. Ideally I would like to automate the updating of the database as soon as my EC2 instance updates with a new csv table. I can do all the de-duping once the table is in the aws MySQL database.

Any advice or link to tutorials on this most welcome. As I stated, I have searched quite a bit for guides but haven't found anything on this. Perhaps the concept is completely wrong and there is an entirely different way of doing it that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't have access to RDS filesystem, therefore cannot upload csv there (and import too).

Modify your Python Scraper to connect to DB directly and insert data there.

Comment: not sure why I didn't think of this earlier, thanks. Found exact tutorial to do this too - https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-mysql-db/

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to run your scraper?

Take a look at this [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html) which will help you configure a Lambda Function to access an Amazon RDS database.

Comment: Hadn't seen this, very useful  thanks! AWS actually has a done of free tutorials..